# Nodemailer TypeError : Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined

Tags: nodemailer

I have a contact-form which is expected to send an email to my website's owner. 
Server is a Node V8 working with Express and NodeMailer  middlewares and is set up as such :

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(
    {host:'ns0.ovh.net',
    port:587,
    secure : false,
    auth:{
        user:'frederic.merle@montardplomberie.fr',
        pass:'xyz'
        }
    }
).verify(function(error, success){
    if (error){
        console.log('server is not ready to take messages')
    }else{
        console.log('server is ready to take messages')
    }
})

api.post('/mail', (req, res) =>{
    console.log("prepare to send mail request")
    if(req.body.company === null){
        req.body.company ="aucun";
    }
    if(req.body.subject === null){
        req.body.subject="aucun";
    }
    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.from,
        to: 'frederic.montard@montardplomberie.fr',
        subject: 'Message reçu de www.montardplomberie.fr',
        text : req.body.msg,
        html :  '<b>De: &nbsp;</b>' + req.body.name +'&nbsp;'+ req.body.surname + '<br>' +
                '<b>Société: &nbsp;</b>' + req.body.company + '<br>'+
                '<b>Objet :&nbsp;</b>' + req.body.subject + '<br>' +
                '<b>Message :&nbsp;</b><br>' + req.body.msg + '<br>' +
                '<b>Coordonnées :&nbsp;</b>' + req.body.tel + '&nbsp;/<br>&nbsp' +req.body.email


    };
    mailer.sendMail(mailOptions, error => console.log(error), info => console.log('Message sent: '+ info.messageId));
    mailer.close();
})
```

However when my request is fired, an error 500 occurs and terminal shows the following :

```
server is ready to take messages
prepare to send mail request
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined
    at api.post (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/server.js:98:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/phmerle/sandbox/gestsoft/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

Having dived into nodemailers documentation it seems transport.sendMail (in my case mailer.sendMail) should be the right method to use and data and callback are passed to the method the right way (in my opinion). What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out ! I simply removed the verify function after nodemailer.createTransport and the sendMail function worked as expected.